# While dragging date from top, i would like to get that list in weekends

Tags: excel, formatting

If i want to drag the date to right/left, i want it in weekend format.
As follows
sun,9/07/2014
sun,9/14/2014
sun,9/21/2014

can anyone provide me the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "weekend format" in Excel, there is only date format. A lot of them, but as formats, they only affect the way the data is shown, not the data itself.

However, if you type the *two* first dates of the series (the 7th and the 14th), and then select them both and drag them, Excel should be able to detect that you want only the sundays, and fill the rest of the series properly.

Answer (score 0):

Define the format in cell formatting to `ddd,mm/dd/yyyy` that should show you the date in the format you need.